# Alphanumeric symbols in the data/app directory?

Tags: adb

Why are the names of the applications replaced with alphanumeric characters in the data/app directory? I am seeing this when accessing the directory through an adb shell.

Comment: See [this question, it's answer and the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47958947/base64-apk-path) for answer to your question.